# Split string on ANY character of a character set

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Is it possible to take a string and do a split based on an character in a character set?

```
let sourceString = "This is the original string/sentence."

let nonAlphabet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").invertedSet

// let words = sourceString.split(charSet:nonAlphabet)
```

In this case words = ["This","is","the","original","string","sentence"]

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
let ss = "This is the original string/sentence."
let arr = ss.characters.split{!s.characters.contains($0)}.map{String($0)}
// ["This", "is", "the", "original", "string", "sentence"]
```

Comment: And here's how I knew how to do that: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_character

Answer (score 1):

`(NS)String` has a method `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`

```
let words = sourceString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(nonAlphabet)
```

The result will have an empty string at the end of the array because of the period.